# .NET MAUI: Customize Shell TitleView and bind to current page title

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui.shell

I want to replace the default Shell header with my own custom layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyNamespace.App.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.App"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.App.Pages"
    BindingContext="{x:Static local:MainView.Instance}"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="{Binding ShellFlyoutType}"
    x:Name="shellMain">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,200">
            <Label BindingContext="{x:Reference shellMain}" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPage.Title, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" />
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="Orange" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>
    
    
    <ShellContent
        Title=" Login"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="login" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" />

    
    <ShellContent Title="Dashboard" 
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:DashboardPage}"
                      Route="dashboard" />
</Shell>
```

I can't manage to bind the current page title.
My AppShell.xaml Shell is declared like `<Shell ... x:Name="shellMain">`

Comment: Show us the whole XAML. I have concerns how you use it. Let me ask directly, is this titleview in your page, or in your shell?

Comment: It's in my shell. I use the AppShell.xaml from the default template.

Answer (score 2):

To be an alternative, you could set the titleview in OnNavigated method:

In AppShell.xaml, define a name for the label

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,200">
        <Label BindingContext="{x:Reference shellMain}" x:Name="mylabel" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" />
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="Orange" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

In AppShell.xaml.cs, override OnNavigated method, get the currentitem

```
protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigated(args);

    var shellItem = Shell.Current?.CurrentItem;
    string title = shellItem?.Title;
    int iterationCount = 0;
    while (shellItem != null
        && title == null)
    {
        title = shellItem.Title;
        shellItem = shellItem.CurrentItem;

        if (iterationCount > 10)
            break;  // max nesting reached

        iterationCount++;
    }

    myLabel.Text = title;
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this workaround did not solve the problem for me on android. Right now I can't test it on windows because of another annoying issue (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080).

Comment: @Benni I put a picture in my answer. Did this what you want for android? This is just using code in my answer for pixel 5 api33.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. My goal was to bind to the current page title not the shell title itself like `<Label BindingContext="{x:Reference shellMain}" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPage.Title}" />`

Comment: Seems we could not bind it in such way, so i tried use another way to achieve. @Benni you could have  a try.

Comment: Thanks for the non MVVM workaround. However sometimes on android the title just disappears. But not all the time. I did adjust your code to work with different `.CurrentItem` levels after navigating to another page. At the moment I can't edit your question because the edit queue is full. I will try later.

Comment: I approve the edit. Did it work for you?

Comment: It shows the title only sometimes. Unfortunately it is not a solution (workaround).

Comment: I also notice that. I think of one stupid but effective way is to write code in each page's OnAppearing method and set the titleview.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed this workaround using view models, not primarily in order to provide an MVVM solution but rather because other suggested answers did not work for me. (I suspect the suggestion in Liqun Shen's comment dated 15 Feb 23 to his own question would work. But I did not notice that till I had made my own fix).

The current page's title is held in a class accessible by the Shell's view model and the view model of each content page:

```
public class ServiceHelper {
    private static ServiceHelper? _default;
    public static ServiceHelper Default => _default ??= new ServiceHelper();
    internal string CurrentPageTitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The view model of each content page within the Shell provides its page title. To facilitate that, most of the work is done by a base view model from which they all derive:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase(string title) : ObservableObject {
    private ServiceHelper? _serviceHelper;
    public string Title { get; } = title;

    internal ServiceHelper ServiceHelper {
        get => _serviceHelper ??= ServiceHelper.Default;
        set => _serviceHelper = value; // For unit testing.
    }

    public virtual void OnAppearing() {
        ServiceHelper.CurrentPageTitle = Title;
    }
}
```

Each shell content page view model only needs to let its base view model know its title:

```
public class LocationsViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public LocationsViewModel() : base("Locations") {
    }
}
```

And each shell content page needs to fire the required event-responding method in its view model:

```
public partial class LocationsPage : ContentPage {
    private LocationsViewModel? _viewModel;

    public LocationsPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private LocationsViewModel ViewModel => 
        _viewModel ??= (LocationsViewModel)BindingContext;

    protected override void OnAppearing() {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ViewModel.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

The Shell's view model provides the current page's title for the title bar:

```
public class AppShellViewModel() : ViewModelBase(Global.ApplicationTitle) {
    private string _currentPageTitle = string.Empty;

    public string CurrentPageTitle {
        get => _currentPageTitle;
        set {
            _currentPageTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnNavigated() {
        CurrentPageTitle = ServiceHelper.CurrentPageTitle;
    }
}
```

And the Shell needs to fire the required event-responding method in its view model:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell {
    private AppShellViewModel? _viewModel;

    public AppShell() {
    InitializeComponent();
    }

    private AppShellViewModel ViewModel => 
    _viewModel ??= (AppShellViewModel)BindingContext;

    protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args) {
        base.OnNavigated(args);
        ViewModel.OnNavigated();
    }
}
```

Finally, the Shell's XAML displays the current page's title, as provided by the Shell's view model, on the title bar / navigation bar:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <HorizontalStackLayout  VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Image Source="falcon_svg_repo_com.png"
               HeightRequest="50"/>
        <Label x:Name="CurrentPageTitleLabel"
               Text="{Binding CurrentPageTitle}"
               FontSize="24"
               Margin="10,0"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to your title in AppShell.xaml like this:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,200">
        <Label x:Name="pageTitle" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" />
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="Orange" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

And then override OnNavigated in AppShell.xaml.cs to update the title. Shell.Current.CurrentPage containts the current page displayed.

```
protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigated(args);
    pageTitle.Text = Current.CurrentPage.Title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same to be able to modify the appearance of the TitleView. It works on iOS although there was another bug there. But on Android I had the same issue. On the forward navigation it updates the title but when you press the back button the title is not updating. I have opened an issue and added a repo as well.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12416#issuecomment-1372627514

Is there another way to modify the appearance of the TitleView?