# How to remove useless header block in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, maui

I have useless block where typed "Вісточка".
How can I remove it?
[image: Useless block]
I just need only "Налаштування" section.
It's Shell with Flyout.
[image]

Comment: please do not post code as images

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75257860/net-maui-customize-shell-titleview-and-bind-to-current-page-title

Comment: Can you show me how you navigated to your current screen, i have a feeling you are using Shell and NavigationPage together

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `NavigationPage` in your App.xaml.cs like this?

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{

   public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


       //MainPage = new AppShell();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AppShell());
    }
    ....
}
```

It can cause this result: *useless block where typed "Вісточка"*. Using `MainPage = new AppShell();` instead can remove it.